# Overflow-x hidden not working in Google Chrome with iFrames

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, iframe

I'm using an iFrame on the following website for the Online Booking system as shown below:

http://www.marandy.com/one2onev2

The iFrame should only display a scroll bar on the y-axis. In Firefox, IE and Safari this is working as expected, however in Google Chrome this is still showing both scroll bars (y & x).

Here is the code:-

HTML

```
        <div id="main-online-booking">

            <iframe id="main-online-frame" class="booking-dimensions" src="http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login-guest.php" frameborder="0"></iframe>

            <div id="main-online-user">

                <a href="#" onclick="changesrc('main-online-frame','http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login.php')"><img alt="One 2 One Account" id="img-onlinebooking-acc" src="images/account.png" /></a>

                <a href="#" onclick="changesrc('main-online-frame','http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login-guest.php')"><img alt="One 2 One Guest" id="img-onlinebooking-guest" src="images/guest.png" /></a>

            </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
#main-online-booking {
    height: 488px;
    border-bottom: 6px #939393 solid;
    border-left: 6px #939393 solid;
    border-right: 6px #939393 solid;
    z-index: 4;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#main-online-frame {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    frameBorder: 0;
    height: 488px;
}
```

The `overflow-x: hidden` property appears to only not be working in Google Chrome on iFrames, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Add in Your iframe `scrolling="no"` and increase height `#main-online-frame`.......

Comment: I have tried this, the problem is that the pages change in height as your making a booking so it cannot be a 'set height'

Comment: I have also tried this, I am still wanting the vertical scroll bar. with scrolling="no" and overflow-x: scroll or auto, it is actually not showing either scroll bar in chrome on an iFrame

Comment: Seems like the `scrolling` attribute is [marked as deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-scrolling)

Answer (score 2):

On page inside your iframe (http://www.marandy.com/one2oneob/login-guest.php), add this `html {overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: auto;}`.

And check initial height of page inside iframe. Make sure that initial height fits in height of iframe.

Comment: would you add this to the body tag?

Comment: In my inspector on Google Chrome, this worked on html tag only. I didn't note any difference if I set this on the body tag.

Comment: I have just updated this, `html {
 background-color:#ffffff;
 overflow-y:hidden;
 overflow-x:hidden; } `and it is still showing the x-scroll
}

Comment: Nope, just vertical. Set `overflow-y: auto;` if you don't want vertical scroll bar by default, and check initial height of page inside iframe. Make sure  that initial height fits in height of iframe.

Comment: Strange, in Chrome, I can still see both horizontal and vertical scroll bars

Comment: I'm using Chrome, and I can see vertical scroll bar only. But if you set inital height on page inside iframe, vertical scroll bar will be visible only if height on some point get bigger value than iframe. Try to clear all cache, or open in incognito window.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue where Chrome was not applying overflow-x:hidden correctly, but all other browsers were.  It wasn't an iFrame, but rather a div.  I struggled with this for about 4 weeks and finally found that if I simply apply position:relative to that same div, it will work properly.  Hopefully this is helpful to someone.